# How to insert 7 into this 2-3 tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am trying to insert the element 7 into this 2-3 tree (see picture):[image]

Since the node containing 6 and 9 is already full, I should move 7 to the parent of 6 and 9, but that node is also already full, so then what do I do?

Comment: shouldn't the end tree look like `(3,6)` as root, then `(1,2), (4,5), (7,9)` as children? Something like: move 6 to parent, which is full, move 5 down to middle child, move 3 up, move 2 down to left node.

Comment: That seems right since the tree will then be balanced, but what steps do you take to get there? How do you reason?

Comment: Isn't this a B-tree? You can easily search the algorithm for insertion/deletion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that the leaf (6, 9) is full and must split when inserting 7. This means that the middle value (which then is 7) must be inserted in the parent node (the root in this case). As you correctly note, that node (2, 5) is also full. So... it must also split. When considering 7, the middle value is 5, which has to move "up". As there is no "up", it will form a new root node:

If we visualise the intermediate, violating states, we get this during the insertion process:

```
              ┌───┬───┐
              │ 2 │ 5 │
              └───┴───┘
             /    |    \
         ┌─┬─┐  ┌─┬─┐  ┌─┬─┬─┐
         │1│ │  │3│4│  │6│7│9│ (overflow)
         └─┴─┘  └─┴─┘  └─┴─┴─┘
```

Then 7 moves up:

```
              ┌───┬───┬───┐
              │ 2 │ 5 │ 7 │ (overflow)
              └───┴───┴───┘
             /    |   |    \
         ┌─┬─┐ ┌─┬─┐ ┌─┬─┐ ┌─┬─┐
         │1│ │ │3│4│ │6│ │ │9│ │ 
         └─┴─┘ └─┴─┘ └─┴─┘ └─┴─┘
```

Then 5 moves up:

```
                   ┌─┬─┐
                   │5│ │
                   └─┴─┘ 
                  /   \
             ┌─┬─┐     ┌─┬─┐
             │2│ │     │7│ │
             └─┴─┘     └─┴─┘
            /   \     /   \
        ┌─┬─┐ ┌─┬─┐ ┌─┬─┐ ┌─┬─┐
        │1│ │ │3│4│ │6│ │ │9│ │
        └─┴─┘ └─┴─┘ └─┴─┘ └─┴─┘
```